# How to get the closest events to a specific event per variable value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I got this table:

| ID | DATE | EVENT | EYE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2022-01-01 | OCT | LEFT |
| 111 | 2022-01-04 | VA | LEFT |
| 111 | 2022-01-05 | INJECTION | LEFT |
| 111 | 2022-06-01 | OCT | RIGHT |
| 111 | 2022-06-01 | VA | RIGHT |
| 111 | 2022-06-05 | OCT | RIGHT |
| 111 | 2022-06-05 | VA | RIGHT |
| 111 | 2022-06-05 | INJECTION | RIGHT |

What I want is a table that gives the CLOSEST events BEFORE "INJECTION" per eye:

Desired output (Ignored rows 4-5):

| ID | DATE | EVENT | EYE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2022-01-01 | OCT | LEFT |
| 111 | 2022-01-04 | VA | LEFT |
| 111 | 2022-01-05 | INJECTION | LEFT |
| 111 | 2022-06-05 | OCT | RIGHT |
| 111 | 2022-06-05 | VA | RIGHT |
| 111 | 2022-06-05 | INJECTION | RIGHT |

What I've tried is:

```sql
WITH T
AS
(
SELECT
     ID,
     DATE,
     EVENT,
     EYE,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,DATE ORDER BY DATE DESC) 
     ELSE NULL END
     AS RN
FROM 
    MY_TABLE
)
SELECT*
FROM T
WHERE RN < 4
```

That works partially - for this specific occasion but not for several ID's.

Comment: I don't follow the logic here, if I am honest. You provide sample data and expected results, but you don't *explain* it; what does "closest" mean? It's not rows that share the same date, so what make something "close"?

Comment: I'll try to explain myself better. I need the 1st 'VA' and the 1st 'OCT' that happened before the 'INJECTION' date, per EYE.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 - 14.0.3451.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` is what you need. Both join to a subselect which allows you to select specific matching criteria, ordering, and most importantly in this case `TOP 3`.

A `CROSS APPLY` is like an (inner) `JOIN`, while `OUTER APPLY` is like a `LEFT JOIN`. Using the latter allows for cases where an injection has no prior event.

The resulting query would be something like:

```
SELECT PRIOR.*
FROM MY_TABLE T
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 3 *
    FROM MY_TABLE T2
    WHERE T2.ID = T.ID
    AND T2.EYE = T.EYE
    AND T2.DATE <= T.DATE  -- Should we allow same-day event?
    ORDER BY T2.DATE DESC
) PRIOR
WHERE T.EVENT = 'INJECTION'
ORDER BY T.ID, T.DATE, T.EYE, PRIOR.DATE
```

Results:

| ID | DATE | EVENT | EYE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2022-01-01 | OCT | LEFT |
| 111 | 2022-01-04 | VA | LEFT |
| 111 | 2022-01-05 | INJECTION | LEFT |
| 111 | 2022-06-05 | VA | RIGHT |
| 111 | 2022-06-05 | OCT | RIGHT |
| 111 | 2022-06-05 | INJECTION | RIGHT |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CzL8va0F) for a demo.

There may still be some ambiguity as to what is considered "before" for same-day events. You might want to look closer at that.

(The above was edited to change `TOP 1` to `TOP 3` after further review of your question.)